# Estimating the deficiency of a group from above

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with a presentation with $k$ generators and $r$ relations. The deficiency $\mathrm{def}~G$ of a group is the maximum of $k-r$ among all presentations. (In my precise case, I am interested in Higman-Thompson groups $V_{n,r}$.)

Suppose we know that, for example, $H_1(G)=H_2(G)=0$. This easily gives the constraint $\mathrm{def}~G \leqslant 0$. I am trying to understand if I could make this inequality strict.

My question is, therefore, as follows: are there ways to get better upper bounds on the deficiency (after applying homology arising restrictions)?

Thank you in advance. I hope that the question is appropriate.

Update: After the comments it seems reasonable to enlarge the question to the following: do any reasonable group properties force some non-homological upper bounds on the deficiency that are, at least sometimes, stronger than the homological ones?

Comment: Just a note that you'll need more conditions because $SL(2,5)$ has deficiency zero and is a superperfect group.

Comment: @SteveD Yes, thank you! There are definitely a lot of examples of deficiency zero superperfect groups. For example, the original Thompson group $F$ is also an example. My question is as well about which conditions or properties to look for if I want to have something better than homology restrictions. There could be some other restrictions that would be stronger than the homology restrictions only in some cases. Sorry if I worded it not in the most understandable way.

Comment: @DenisGorodkov Just pointing out $F$ isn't superperfect (but it does have deficiency zero). Do you mean $V$? That is superperfect (but I don't know its deficiency).

Comment: @MattZaremsky Yes, I apparently mixed them up... Thank you for your comment! I did not find anything about the deficiency of $V$ as well.

Comment: In general, it's an extremely difficult problem to find non-homological bounds on the deficiency. Indeed, in a sense, the Relation Gap Problem (which is still open for finitely presented groups) asks for just this.

Comment: Steve Pride showed that groups of deficiency >1 are “large”, meaning they virtually surject a non-abolish free group. So if your group isn’t large, its deficiency is at most  1.

Comment: *abelian${}{}{}$

Comment: Sorry to keep commenting. It's rather an open-ended question, which provokes several different responses. Another obstacle to what you want is that we still know very little about deficiency-zero (aka "balanced" presentations). There are several notorious open problems, including the triviality problem. Of course $\mathrm{def}(G)<0$ implies that $G$ is non-trivial...

Comment: @HJRW Thank you for your insightful comments, I think that I understand the difficulty of the problem much better now.

Comment: @DenisGorodkov: Did you ever find anything more about the group V? I would be interested to know if it has a deficiency 0 presentation.

Comment: @DannyRuberman Sadly, no: it seems that the question does not have a known (or reasonably easy) answer. However, I was more interested in a family of examples, and did not explicitly research $V$ specifically.